# Knowing if the currently logged-in user has seen the list of nodes shown in a view

Tags: views

I use the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module to show a list of specific nodes. Is there a way to know if the currently logged-in user has seen the list of nodes?

Comment: Please choose one question to post here, and post a second question with the other one.  Two questions per question defeats the usefulness of StackExchange sites.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best option for you is to write a mini module with  a simple DB table. If you need designing it i will help you.

Also try the [checklist module](https://drupal.org/project/checklist)

Maybe it could help you

Comment: Thank you. I know how to design the table, but I don't know how to change the query results of a view to add the field I defined in my own module.

Comment: I'll try to to make some order here.
If you want to check if a current user has seen a page or not, you need to store some type of flag somewhere(meaning "1 = yes he did"  "0 = not he didn't")
If you want to update that flag after a user has seen a node, you can do so with a banch of options(rules, triggers, adding some php code to your view etc...)

Answer (score 0):

add a list of users to your node type , create a new [rule](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) on node view event , add user to that list , this list can be hidden using [field permission](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions)

it is easy , and fast because you don't need any sql search to check who has seen it.

Comment: Do you mean add a custom field whose type is EntityReference and have unlimited values? That sounds great. I finally used a custom module to track a user's list.

Comment: Yep , that would be easy and fast in queries